# Can I use "In love with" something instead of somebody?

Tags: expressions

Does it sound fluent when a sportsman says "I'm in love with sport" or a musician says "I'm in love with music"? Or there are better ways to say this?

Comment: Hi alisun and welcome to ELU! The short answer to your question is yes, it is fluent.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELU. The slightly longer answer is that to "love" sports/music/etc is somewhat different from being "in love" with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OED does not specify that being **in love (with)** is only applicable to a person or other living thing.

> **love**
>
> **a. in love (with):** enamoured (of), filled with love (for); (in extended use) very fond (of), much addicted (to). In quot. a1398: †in heat (obs.). See also mad in love at mad adv. 2b   and madly in love at madly adv. 2a.

In fact, it provides some quotations that describe being in love with things:

> a1616   Shakespeare Two Gentlemen of Verona (1623) ii. i. 76   **I was in loue with my bed.**
>
> 1969   J. McPhee Levels of Game 10   **He is in love with his work.** He knows the exact height and tensile strength of the corporate ladder.

However, the usual way would just be to say *I love [sth.]* See @Lawrence's comment.

Comment: +1. Although I would add (based on my own experience) that for something generic like "sport" or "music" I agree with @Lawrence that "I love [sport/music]" is more natural than "I'm *in love with* [sport/music]". However, if being poetic, you can use "in love with" for something more specific, as per your examples.

Comment: @AndyT 'Based on my own experience'... Sounds like there's a story there!

Comment: Ha, sorry, no. Perhaps a better phrase would be "in my idiolect".

Comment: Although we do classify "in love with Tom" as a higher order of love compared to "loving basketball", it seems acceptable to say that you are "in love with basketball" if you are trying to stress that you love it more than one would normally love a sport. It is an overstatement, just like how you would call someone "strong like a bear" without suggesting that they are _literally_ as strong as a bear.